# How to get H2O automl working from command line using CURL?

Tags: h2o

I am trying to launch H2O AutoML from command line with CURL and could not get it working..

The base command is something as below:

`curl -X POST -H 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d 'training_frame=12cfbae9-af66-42fd-835f-13ccc5a508ab'  "http://localhost:54321/99/AutoMLBuilder"`

I tried with various parameters with but I always get error as unknown parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the use the CURL command as below to make it work:

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"input_spec":{"training_frame":"1acfbae9-af66-42fd-835f-13ccc5a508cb","response_column":"mpg","ignored_columns":[],"sort_metric":null},"build_models":{"exclude_algos":[]},"build_control":{"nfolds":5,"keep_cross_validation_predictions":true,"keep_cross_validation_models":true,"balance_classes":false,"class_sampling_factors":[],"max_after_balance_size":5,"stopping_criteria":{"seed":-1,"max_models":0,"max_runtime_secs":30,"stopping_rounds":3,"stopping_tolerance":-1},"project_name":"automl-mpg"}}' http://localhost:54321/99/AutoMLBuilder`

Above 1acfbae9-af66-42fd-835f-13ccc5a508cb is the training frame id.